# How to draw a 2 mean line plots with CI in 1 plot

Tags: r, plot, mean, confidence-interval

I'm trying to draw 2 line of means in one plot with the CI. I used `gplots` which has function `plotmeans` to draw a line but I only can draw one line in one plot. Anyone could help? Thanks a lot

This is an example of my data

```
Group  MC  MB
G1     5    10
G2     8    8
G3     14   7  
G4     20   6
G1     10   15
G2     16   13   
G3     30   9
G4     25   7
G1     15   29
G2     20   22
G3     25   20
G4     35   15
```

I would like to plot MC and MB as a line which the value is a mean value and CI at each group. The `xlab` will be `group`. `ylab` is the value of `MC` and `MB`.

I would expect something like this
[image]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a combination of tidyr, dplyr and ggplot2.

```
# Your data
group <- c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4", "G1", "G2", "G3", "G4", "G1", "G2", "G3", "G4")
mc <- c(5, 8, 14, 20, 10, 16, 30, 25, 15, 20, 25, 35)
mb <- c(10, 8, 7, 6, 15, 13, 9, 7, 29, 22, 20, 15)
df <- data.frame(group, mc, mb)
```

First we gather your data to long format with the columns category (cat) and value.

```
# Requires library "tidyr"
library(tidyr)

# Gathering data
df_gathered <- gather(df, cat, value, 2:3)
```

Next you calculate the mean and error for each combination of group and category:

```
# Requires the library "dplyr"
library(dplyr)

# Calculating mean and error by group
df_mean_by_group <- df_gathered %>% 
  group_by(group, cat) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value), error = qnorm(0.975)*sd(value)/length(value))
```

Finally we plot grouping the lines by category (to connect them), and we color them also by category:

```
# Requires "ggplot2"
library(ggplot2)

# Plotting it all
ggplot(df_mean_by_group, aes(x=group, y=mean, colour=cat, group=cat)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-error, ymax=mean+error), colour="black", width=.1) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size=3)
```

[image]